# Распаковка zip архива с помощью Zipper выдает ошибку "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, laravel, zip

Использую пакет https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper

В архиве имеются файлы .xsd, возможно это не относиться конкретно к этому файлу, а может проблемы именно с ними.

Пытаюсь распаковать архив:

```
$this->zipper->make(resource_path('/templates/ScormDriver_scorm2004_4th.zip'))
        ->extractTo($this->sourcePath());
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
file_put_contents(//ScormEnginePackageProperties.xsd): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Пробовал уже задавать права через chmod 777 но ничего.

Answer (score 3):

Всё дело в том что возвращает метод `sourcePath()`. А он возвращает `'/'` и поэтому обращается в корень системы и потому нету прав.